# Android: accessing Linux PC?

Tags: network-shares, file-sharing, remote, android

I'm looking for a way to access my home box PC drive (Linux-based) on Android. What can I use for that? ATM I've found only FTP and SSHFS, both are slow and have issues (couldn't even install SSHFS on JellyBeans).

Comment: Seems I've solved problem partly: CIFSmanager + samba on Linux PC, but  thats imho overkill.

Comment: That seems horribly inefficient for two linux based PCs. Avoid CIFS/SMB whenever possible, very slow and inefficient protocols. I would think there would be something that uses NFS. I personally have not used an android phone, but seems like mount would be a good options: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=718719

Comment: it is indeed, but i didn't find any apps to mount NFS nor mount command did that.

Answer (score 0):

I do this using Samba on my Linux box, and then I download ESFile Explorer to my Androiid phone.  ESFile Explorer lets me access my SAMBA shares without any problems.

Sharing in Ubuntu through the graphical file explorer is supposed to be easy, but I have learned that if I want it to work right the first time, as well as every time I reboot, I have to go in and manually add the shared folder to the /etc/samba/smb.conf file.

ESFile explorer also streams my movies and music without and problem.  (Your version of Android must have FUSE Support)

Comment: after all i've rooted my android and set there Cifs manager :(